# Django: How to show Groups field in Custom UserAdmin?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I created a custom User class, and a custom UserAdmin / Form class.   Everything looks fine, but I'm still missing the `groups` field (auth_group). 
I don`t know the field name.

https://gist.github.com/CoinBR/c49c05f24bd5dcd3b4d4f2d205143a2e

Django Version: 1.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see inside the `PermissionsMixin` class:

```
"""
A mixin class that adds the fields and methods necessary to support
Django's Group and Permission model using the ModelBackend.
"""
...
groups = models.ManyToManyField(
    Group,
    verbose_name=_('groups'),
    blank=True,
    help_text=_(
        'The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions '
        'granted to each of their groups.'
    ),
    related_name="user_set",
    related_query_name="user",
)
...
```

so it's name is `groups`. You must add it in fields of `UserCreateForm` and fieldsets of `UserAdmin`.